# Should I push my dependency (jar library) while using source code control

Tags: java, git, google-app-engine, github

Usually when I am not using maven, My project have a tons of library file
For example, A normal GAE will have at least 40MB of jar file

Should I avoid push this file to the repository ?( and how to avoid it)
If not , How can I manage this situation(somethings,I just have a really slow network)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GAE jars themselves are really big, so if you push the jars to git and update them a couple of times your repo will get pretty big.
We still use something like Maven to handle dependencies.

Comment: maven is a great solution, but cost a long build time

Answer (score 0):

Push all jar dependencies to the repo, so that your project is self-contained.

40 MB isn't that much space, and you have to push these jars only once - they're not updated very often.